# How to display images in real mode?

Tags: assembly, linker, operating-system, kernel, bootloader

I am learning Operating Systems. I have been through the Boot loaders and kernel. When I was using the XP OS, I suddenly wondered of how to display a image (say logo.jpg) in real mode using a second stage boot loader. Is it possible to do so?

Because I thought the XP logo that is displayed during bootup is at real mode.

So, How can I do that?
ie: My boot loader loads a second stage and the second stage should load the image file and display it.

Should I be using the resource linker or something?

Language : 8086 assembly

Thanks

Comment: With a VESA VBE 3-bios of modern display devices we can switch into a videomode with 8,16, or 24/32 bits for colors maybe with a widescreen resolution example with 1920x1200x32 (16:10 aspect ratio). More details can be found inside the public und costfree document "vbe3.pdf" from vesa.org (need register/login).Older videomodes with only 4 bits and 16 colors are not very easy to use, because it is not so performant for to need a port access for to set every single pixel.

Comment: Yes, but usually you don't want to make optimistic assumptions about the available hardware in your bootloader or such... That's why even modern Windows can display a non-VESA bootscreen (and did by default until Windows Vista if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can interact with the BIOS using interrupt 10h to control the video card.

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H
Tutorial "Video Programming I": http://fleder44.net/312/notes/18Graphics/index.html

Here is an example, taken from [this website](http://www.fysnet.net/modex.htm) ([license](http://www.fysnet.net/legal.htm)):

> Here is an example of MODE 12h video graphics with 4 plains using Write Mode 2.
>   Simply draws a colorful line from (0,0) to (479,479) on the 640x480x16 screen.
>       ; This code was assembled with NBASM
>
> ```
> .model tiny
> .code
> .186
>
>            org 100h
>
>            mov  ax,0012h                ; set mode to 640x480x16
>            int  10h
>
>            mov  ax,0A000h
>            mov  es,ax
>
>            ; start line from (0,0) to (639,479)
>            mov  word X,0001h            ; top most pixel (0,0)
>            mov  word Y,0001h            ;
>            mov  byte Color,00h          ; start with color 0
>            mov  cx,480                  ; 480 pixels
> DrawLine:  call putpixel                ; put the pixel
>            inc  word X                  ; move down a row and inc col
>            inc  word Y                  ;
>            inc  byte Color              ; next color
>            and  byte Color,0Fh          ; 00h - 0Fh only
>            loop DrawLine                ; do it
>
>            xor  ah,ah                   ; wait for key press
>            int  16h
>
>            mov  ax,0003                 ; return to screen 3 (text)
>            int  10h
>
>            .exit                        ; exit to DOS
>
>
> ; on entry X,Y = location and C = color (0-15)
> putpixel   proc near uses ax bx cx dx
>
> ; byte offset = Y * (horz_res / 8) + int(X / 8)
>
>            mov  ax,Y                    ; calculate offset
>            mov  dx,80                   ;
>            mul  dx                      ; ax = y * 80
>            mov  bx,X                    ;
>            mov  cl,bl                   ; save low byte for below
>            shr  bx,03                   ; div by 8
>            add  bx,ax                   ; bx = offset this group of 8 pixels
>
>            mov  dx,03CEh                ; set to video hardware controller
>
>            and  cl,07h                  ; Compute bit mask from X-coordinates
>            xor  cl,07h                  ;  and put in ah
>            mov  ah,01h                  ;
>            shl  ah,cl                   ;
>            mov  al,08h                  ; bit mask register
>            out  dx,ax                   ;
>
>            mov  ax,0205h                ; read mode 0, write mode 2
>            out  dx,ax                   ;
>
>            mov  al,es:[bx]              ; load to latch register
>            mov  al,Color
>            mov  es:[bx],al              ; write to register
>
>            ret
> putpixel   endp
>
> X          dw 00h
> Y          dw 00h
> Color      db 00h
>
> .end
> ```

Comment: Actually can I display an image(say logo.jpg) in the real mode? I don't want to draw graphics instead display the image.

Comment: Same thing. It would be unnecessarily complex to decode JPG though. Just store it as bitmap or even raw pixel data. Then go and draw all the pixels to the screen. Boom, you just displayed an image.

Comment: Ok, but how should I fetch pixel from bitmap file and draw it?

Comment: You are writing a kernel, right? Did you already build a file system? Otherwise there is nothing such as a "file" yet at all... If you don't have a way to load things from disk yet, you would need to include the pixels as array in your code.